# Handling HTTP Query Parameters

Tags: python, rest, query-string

I have a simple server that will return JSON to a user. I want the to provide some inputs to the service, so I use query parameters:

```
/path?paramName=paramValue&paramName2=paramValue2....&paramNamen=paramValuen
```

In Python, what is the best way of parsing out these parameters?

My server is a threaded server defined as such:

```
class ThreadingSimpleServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,
                            BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    """ simple threaded server """
    pass
```

In my request handler, I implemented a `do_GET()`.

Should I have this function split based on the `?` to separate out the path from the parameters and then split again on the `&` or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions from [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
import urllib.parse

u = "http://java.dzone.com/articles/python-201-decorators?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fpython+%28Python+Zone%29"
p = urllib.parse.urlparse(u)
q = urllib.parse.parse_qs(p.query)
print(q)
```

Output:

```
{'utm_campaign': ['Feed: zones/python (Python Zone)'],
 'utm_medium': ['feed'],
 'utm_source': ['feedburner']}
```